# Splash Screen with images and texts for Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I need create a background and then on top of that the text boxes and images as Splash Screen. What my steps?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two activities. One activity is used to show the splash screen and the other used to show the mian activity.

splashscreen.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/star"/>
<TextView
    android:text="Splash Screen Star"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

SplashScreen_Activity:

```
 public class SplashScreen_Activity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.splashscreen);
        // Create your application here
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }
    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.            
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(Activity5)));
    }
}
```

Activity5 is the main activity i want to show. You could load the layout in Activity5.

Answer (score -2):

I really don't understand why you would be advising a user to use such an outdated technique of suggesting the use of SplashScreen Activity, for a splash screen when obviously there are far better techniques of achieving a SplashScreen. You are offering a solution that was even frowned upon back in 2016-16, let alone 2022.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you were to propose an alternative, less outdated technique rather than just a critique of the proposed solution.

Comment: @Iain Carlin, Yes you're right. Please see the following link https://github.com/gmck and then check NavigationGraph5